# Getting checked checkboxes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have an array containing the days of the week. It looks like this:

```
$scope.days=[{id:0, day: 'Monday'},{id:1, day: 'Tuesday'},{id:2, day: 'Wednesday'},{id:3, day: 'Thursday'}, {id:4, day: 'Friday'}, {id:5, day:'Saturday'}, {id:6, day:'Sunday'}];
```

and a user with a string containing the days he/she is available:

```
$scope.user={"userdays":"1011111"};;
```

1 = available, 0=unavailable.

I bind it to a list of checkboxes like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="day in days">
  <input  ng-model="userdays[day.id]" ng-checked="user.userdays[day.id]!=0" type="checkbox" />
{{day.day}}</p>
```

creating a list of checkboxes for the array of days and checking the days, the user is available.

Whenever a change occurs, I add the day to a property:

```
$scope.userdays={};
```

I would then like to save the days the user is available. But unless I make a change (ie click on one of the checkboxes), the $scope.userdays-property does not contain anything, and it only contains the value of the checkbox I have interacted with.

My question is, how do I get the values of all the checked checkboxes, regardless of whether I have actually clicked one of the checkboxes?

I have created a plunker here,showing my current implementation:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Yrr2wrcoUno6tzgBgOMa?p=preview

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for loop to set the initial state

Check the update [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5x4FsbbC0aclrcENcOeI?p=preview)